# Visual Studio unit test not working and not showing tests

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, log4net

I am following [MSDocs guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470.aspx) to put up some unit testing. I've never used them before and I've never been using them because to me they are totally useless, but I see it's a common practice, so I wanted to learn more.

Obviously, this is not working.

I've put up some .NET Standard 2.0 libraries with little to no code to do some [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) logging. I've addet a "Unit test project" as the guide suggests and added a method decorated with the "TestMethod" attribute and all the other attributes.

Test explorer windows does not show any test and I'm not able to even run them in any way. What am I missing?

Here's the code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MrLogger_netstandard;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ErrorLogOnFile_Default() => MrLogger.Instance.FileErrorLog("I'M AN ERROR!!! :)");
    }
}
```

The MrLogger class it's just a class that does logger.Debug("Write message"), a classical log4net logging call.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298347/nunit-unit-tests-not-showing-in-test-explorer-with-test-adapter-installed) too and it changes nothing.

Jeez... help

Comment: Try creating a new default test project. File->New->Project ->Visual C#-> Test.   It should create one empty test. then Test->Run->All tests, and see if it runs 1 test

Comment: Tried to do that, rebuild solution as visual studio suggests and change even test architecture again, but no test is discovered. Test->Run->All tests is greyed out because there is no test available. I've tried to create Visual C# and NET Core unit tests but no luck.

Comment: I had a similar problem once. Perhaps the vs execution process is dead or hung. Take a look at some of the solutions here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664886/error-debugging-code-in-visual-studio-2012-failed-to-initialize-client-proxy/

Comment: @user889742 That post led me to the solution. It was administrator rights.... UGH.... that's dumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I had to start visual studio as administrator and then it worked.... UGH! :(