# Make Visual Studio 2012 find and run both x64 and x86 unit tests in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

In my solution I have one unit test project explicitly targeting x86 platform and one unit test project explicitly targeting x64 platform.
To get Visual Studio 2012 to find and run my unit tests, I have to setup the default processor architecture for unit testing via

```
Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture
```

like stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116817/1814576

The problem is, when I do that for my x86 tests, Visual Studio does not find my x64 tests and vice versa. The tests even don't run, when trying to start them directly via `right click->Run Tests` 
from source code.

Is there a way to setup the testing framework so that both my x86 and my x64 tests are found and run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'ge going to want to set your build to Mixed Platform

[image]