# C# async Task - Unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

I am new to C# unit testing and have to test if the method is working properly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(API_FIRM_LINK aPI_FIRM_LINK)
    {
        db.API_FIRM_LINK.Add(aPI_FIRM_LINK);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created(aPI_FIRM_LINK);
    }
```

test method: Not really sure if I am on the right path
If someone could provide an example based on my test

```
     public async Task PostTest()

    {
        ////Arrange
        API_FIRM_LINKController controller = new API_FIRM_LINKController();

        API_FIRM_LINK aPI_FIRM_LINK = null;

        IHttpActionResult expectedResult = await controller.Post(aPI_FIRM_LINK);
        //act

        IHttpActionResult result = await controller.Post(API_FIRM_LINK, aPI_FIRM_LINK);


        ////Assert
        IComparer<IHttpActionResult> comparer = new IHttpActionResultComparer();
       // Assert.IsTrue(comparer.Equals(expectedResult, result));

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: Don't use `async void`.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: Thanks.. To be honest I am new to this - I am trying to set up a test and not really sure how to approach a method that check if its working properly

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19317319/5803406) provides some insight as to why `async void` won't work in unit tests

Comment: Console result = System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1{System.Web.Http.IHttoActionResult ] so far

Comment: @devNull any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a modern version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` you can use an async test method, like you do in your question.

If you want to Test whether your Post function returns the expected data, do the following:

```
[TestMethod()]
public async Task PostTestAsync()
{
    var controller = new API_FIRM_LINKController();
    // TODO: do some preparations, so you can expect a specific return value
    IHttpActionResult expectedResult = ...

    // call PostAsync and await for it to finish
    Task taskPost =  controller.PostAsync(API_FIRM_LINK, aPI_FIRM_LINK);
    IHttpActionResult result = await taskPost;

    // of course this can be done in one line:
    IHttpActionResult result = await controller.PostAsync(API_FIRM_LINK, aPI_FIRM_LINK);

    // compare whether result equals expectedResult
    // for example: create a class that implements IComparer<IHttpActionResult>
    IComparer<IHttpActionResult> comparer = new IHttpActionResultComparer();
    Assert.IsTrue(comparer.Equals(expectedResult, result);
}
```

If you use a test suite where you can't use async tests:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void PostTest()
{
    var controller = new API_FIRM_LINKController();
    IHttpActionResult expectedResult = ...

    // call PostAsync and wait for it to finish
    Task taskPost =  Task.Run(() => controller.PostAsync(API_FIRM_LINK, aPI_FIRM_LINK));
    taskPost.Wait();
    IHttpActionResult result = taskPost.Result;

    // TODO: compare result with expected result
}
```

Comment: I tried to make some adjustments since most of it was breaking and not able to build it.    await controller.PostAsync(API_FIRM_LINK, aPI_FIRM_LINK)  get the following message:  API_FIRM_LINK is a type - not valid . and  aPI_FIRM_LINK does not exist.

Comment: I only copy-pasted the call to method Post from the code in your question. The only change I made was rename it to PostAsync, to match the more common name of an async function. I assumed you knew how to program and could see through this small change. Of course you should use Post if your code is called Post!

Comment: I am new to it..so I am doing some research on it. Thanks for the help

Comment: This "async Task" solved my problem trying for 2 hours. Actually failed to identify where the problem is. Thank you very much Harald.

Answer (score 5):

Never `async void`, basically.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task PostTest() {...}
```

If your testing framework doesn't support `Task` tests: change testing framework.

Comment: But how could I write a test that check if it works correctly or not -

Comment: @usertestREACT `await Task.Delay(500); Assert.Fail();` - if it doesn't fail, it isn't working

Comment: await controller.Post(API_FIRM_LINK aPI_FIRM_LINK); error here:     API_FIRM_LINK is a type which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Console result = System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1{System.Web.Http.IHttoActionResult ]  so far

Comment: @MarcGravell what's the downside of using `async void` on a `[TestMethod]`?

Comment: @MuhammadMamoorKhan the test runner doesn't know when the operation has completed, so could incorrectly report a test as successful, when it is still running asynchronously and could still fail; consider: `[TestMethod] public async void Simple() { await Task.Yield(); Assert.Fail(); }` - now make it `async Task` and it works correctly (i.e. reports failure)