# Why Does Visual Studio not give me a test in Test explorer when I build my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium, nunit, phantomjs

I have attempted this in a few ways but never have a test after I hit build I have written a test using Nunit and am not sure what I need to do.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;

namespace sampletest {
  [TestFixture()]
  public class phantom { 
    [Test()]
    public void TestCase() {
      IWebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.PhantomJS());
      try {
        wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        wd.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).Click();
        wd.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).Clear();
        wd.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("blah");
        wd.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).Click();

        wd.FindElement(By.LinkText("linkedtext")).Click();
        Assert.AreEqual(wd.Title, "PageTitle");
      } finally { wd.Quit(); }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons it can happen.

- make sure you have the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) (Nuget is an option for installing that) installed.
- After that go to TEST-->Test Settings-->Default Processor Architecture and select the correct processor for your machine.
- Do a BUILD-->Clean Solution and then Build Solution

There are other reasons it may happen. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533259/why-does-visual-studio-2012-not-find-my-tests)

Comment: Saifur yes Nunit Test Adapter is installed. I have also tryed not using Nunit Framework withTest Methods and still nothing is this a Visual Studio 2013 issue?