# Why do I need to run as administrator for unit tests to work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

When I run Visual Studio Professional 2013 under my regular user account, I can debug/test ASP.NET applications but I can't run the unit tests for some reason.  It looks like it discovers the unit tests at first ("Discover tests finished: 4 found") but then doesn't run them ("no tests found to run").

When I run VS as administrator, it works.  I got the idea from  [Why does visual studio 2012 not find my tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533259/why-does-visual-studio-2012-not-find-my-tests) but the answers don't explain *why* it makes a difference.
Running unit tests doesn't seem like something that should require admin rights.

Comment: What's the nature of the unit tests - are you using the built in testing (mstest) or some other framework?

Comment: Yes, it's built-in testing (MSTest) - `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to run as administrator for unit tests to work

It depends on the nature of your test cases.

[Why Visual Studio should run as an Administrator](http://blog.peterritchie.com/?p=821).

> - Developing for Windows Azure
> - Coded UI tests
> - Using IIS with web application
> - Developing with WCF  Profiling
> - Installing updates for various extensions (like NuGet)

You can set `devenv.exe` to **Run as Administrator** under Properties and Compatibility tab as a workaround.

Comment: I'm not sure those apply - I have unit tests for a controller that are just making normal method calls and assertions.

Comment: @wrschneider: May be a VS bug... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807771/visual-studio-2013-test-explorer-only-works-if-run-as-administrator

Comment: @CharithJ - the VS Bug link just goes to bing lol